# How can I configure set-revolver in a multi-project build.sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt

Can somebody provide me with an example `build.sbt` file showing how to use revolver with multiple projects?

Specifically where should the `Revolver.settings` statement go, at the top level or in one or more of the sub-projects? The top level does not work for me and I cannot add it to a sub-project without the build breaking.

For what it's worth when I add the settings at the project top-level I get the following error

```
> project backend
> re-start 2551
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: re-start
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '::'
[error] Not a valid key: re-start (similar: state, startYear, cross-target)
[error] re-start 2551
[error]         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you need to create a second `build.sbt` file in the sub-projects directory, and put the settings for it there. An example of this stub build file is below:

```
Revolver.settings

javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Djava.library.path=lib")

javaOptions in Revolver.reStart ++= Seq("-Dconfig.resource=dev.conf", "-Djava.library.path=src/universal/lib")

mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some("com.example.Main")
```

Comment: You don't need a separate build file.  Simply place those settings in the subproject settings.